# Can anyone identify this bug/insect?

Tags: species-identification

[image: Saw this bug/insect/spider? on a ranch in Santa Ynez, CA. Pretty fast moving-this was the only photo I could get. The creature is the thing in the photo that looks like two puff balls on a very black body. (The smaller puff is the front of the body.) Maybe a bumble bee? Did not appear to have wings...]!Saw this bug/insect/spider? on a ranch in Santa Ynez, CA. Pretty fast moving-this was the only photo I could get. The creature is the thing in the photo that looks like two puff balls on a very black body. (The smaller puff is the front of the body.) Maybe a bumble bee? Did not appear to have wings.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Can you please indicate the approximate size and speed (as well as mode) of displacement. It might be hard to say anything with this picture.

Comment: You might want to edit the post to improve the grammar, start sentences with a capitalize letter and don't end sentences with things like `...!]`

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps it was a species of velvet ant (a type of wasp from the genus *Dasymutilla*). The females lack wings, and it appears like what you describe and vaguely see in your image.

Here are some photos:

[image]

[image]

[Photo 1 Source](http://www.whatsthatbug.com/category/wasps-and-hornets/velvet-ants/page/14/)

[Photo 2/Information Source](http://ucanr.edu/blogs/blogcore/postdetail.cfm?postnum=6041)